# Converting a sphere equation to a homogenous one to obtain the equation of a cone

Tags: analytic-geometry, 3d, quadrics

> A variable plane parallel to the plane
> $\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}+\frac{z}{c}=0$ meets the coordinate axes at
> $A, B, C$. Find the equation of the cone whose vertex is at the origin
> and the guiding curve is the circle $ABC$.

I have found out that the equation of the circle $ABC$ is $\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}+\frac{z}{c}=k$,  $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}-k(ax+by+cz)=0$. ($k$ is a constant and the sphere taken passes through the points $A, B, C, O$.)

Now, given the vertex and guiding curve, I know how to find the equation of the cone using the normal method. After some calculation, I eventually obtained the equation of the cone to be:
$$x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}-(\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}+\frac{z}{c})(ax+by+cz)=0$$
However, it seems there is a shortcut to solving this particular question. Substitute the value of $k$ from the plane equation in the sphere equation to make the sphere equation homogenous, and there you have it—the equation of the required cone!

I don't really understand this shortcut. I do know that a quadric cone with its vertex at the origin will be a homogeneous second-degree equation, but I don't get this shortcut. A proper explanation will be of great help!

Comment: (Only a rephrasing) Considering it one dimension up by viewing $k$ as a variable, then it's all homogeneous, and projecting down by eliminating $k$ from your two equations (a plane in ${\Bbb P}^3$ and full rank quadric (a hyperboloid of two sheets in the affine $z=1$)) gives your cone in 3d / conic in ${\Bbb P}^2.$

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland I do understand that substituting $k$ will make the equation homogeneous and hence it would become the equation of a quadric cone whose vertex is at origin, but what I don't understand is how that cone is actually the same cone that is required by the question.

Comment: There cannot be much more to it, the cone is in the ideal. And the ideals $\langle \frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}+\frac{z}{c}-k,x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}-k(ax+by+cz)\rangle$ and $\langle \frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}+\frac{z}{c}-k,x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}-(\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}+\frac{z}{c})(ax+by+cz)\rangle$ are equal.